# Nginx and Jenkins configuration

Tags: nginx, jenkins, reverse-proxy

I have 2 VMs (VM1 and VM2), and want to build the following infrastructure:

- VM1 will be an entry point, and I need to install Jenkins and Nginx. Jenkins is just for CI/CD pipelines, and nginx acts as a reverse proxy and load balancer.
- VM2 Tomcat as the application server for Java applications

I have a problem with access to the Jenkins

I made the following config:

Nginx

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name VM1_IP;

    location /jenkins {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Jenkins

```
JENKINS_ARGS="--webroot=.... --httpPort=$HTTP_PORT --prefix=/jenkins"
```

Jenkins URL

```
http://VM1_IP/jenkins
```

For some reason I'm not able to access Jenkins, in theory, Jenkins should be accessible at `http://VM1_IP/jenkins`, but it redirects me to the login, and returns 404 :(

What did I do wrong?

Comment: In my case, the issue was with the jenkins service, fixed by adding this:

[Service]
Environment="JENKINS_PREFIX=/jenkins"

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `proxy_redirect` directive to replace any redirect headers.

```
location /jenkins {
      proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8080;
      proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8080/ http://VM1_IP/;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Include this configuration -->

```
      proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8080;
      proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8080/ http://VM1_IP/;
}
```

Within

```
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
```